# How can I change the orientation of a gradient line in html between different screen sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My problem is that I have created some vertical gradient lines between divs in html. I turn them off when moving to mobile view with @media queries. What I want to do is to change the orientation of these lines into horizontal when moving to mobile-view. I'm using bootstrap classes and I need to take into acccount the mobile-first approach.

To sum up: 
NOT on mobile-view --> Vertical lines
When ON mobile view --> Horizontal lines

Here is my HTML:

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 VerticalAfter">
                SOME TEXT
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4"> 
                SOME TEXT
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 VerticalBefore">
                SOME TEXT
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .VerticalAfter:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
      color-stop(0%,rgba(208,228,247,0)),
      color-stop(24%,rgba(115,177,231,0.48)),
      color-stop(50%,rgba(12,16,255,1)),
      color-stop(79%,rgba(83,159,225,0.42)),
      color-stop(100%,rgba(135,188,234,0))
    );
    right: 0;
  }

  .VerticalBefore:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
      color-stop(0%,rgba(208,228,247,0)),
      color-stop(24%,rgba(115,177,231,0.48)),
      color-stop(50%,rgba(12,16,255,1)),
      color-stop(79%,rgba(83,159,225,0.42)),
      color-stop(100%,rgba(135,188,234,0))
    );
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linear-gradient syntax you're using is from and old webkit implementation and should definitely NOT be used anymore!

You may simply use

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(208,228,247,0) 0%, rgba(115,177,231,0.48) 24%, rgba(12,16,255,1) 50%, rgba(83,159,225,0.42) 79% rgba(135,188,234,0) 100%);
```

And adapt this to the desktop view by replacing `ro right` with `to bottom`:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(208,228,247,0) 0%, rgba(115,177,231,0.48) 24%, rgba(12,16,255,1) 50%, rgba(83,159,225,0.42) 79% rgba(135,188,234,0) 100%);
}
```

edit: How to use linear-gradient(): https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: Why do you actually say that I should definately not use this webkit implementation? With what I used the code is working but just on the vertical orientation.. your solution is something that I cant make it work though...

Comment: @Chris Mos - because the webkit prefix you use is outdated and may stop working anytime.